# Comparing three variables in R and mapping it by grouping on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, datatables, maps, grouping

I have three variables in R that I want to compare. I am having trouble figuring out the coding to analyze this data and was wondering if anyone could help.

This table is looking at the zip codes, breaking them out by industry and by type (A,B,C,D). I want to essentially sum up all values by type (A,B,C,D) within zip. From there I want to exclude all zips below a certain number to only look at relevant data points.

Lastly -  I am trying to plot this on ggplot, a map of the US - plotting all users by color by industry...but ggplot is not intuitive and I'm having trouble plotting the points properly.

Raw Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R1NeFTuvvhqnxG-SgABevJjPflyaG_P1btmwyD2hB-c/edit?usp=sharing

My code so far:

```
ftable(body_industry$postalcode,body_industry$industry,body_industry$reclass_bodytype)

#My initial thought was to use addmargins(ftable(body_industry...) 
but this doesn't seem to be working as the data set doesn't sum up properly.
```

```
 Zip     Industry           A    B    C    D
 94801   artistic           0    0    0    0
         banking            0    0    0    0
         clerical           0    0    0    0
         computer           0    1    0    0
         construction       1    0    0    0
         education          1    0    0    0
         entertainment      0    0    0    0
         executive          0    0    0    0
         hospitality        0    0    0    0
         law                0    0    0    0
         medicine           0    0    0    0
         military           0    0    0    0
         political          0    0    0    0
         retired            0    0    0    0
         sales              0    0    0    1
         science            0    0    0    0
         student            0    0    0    0
         transportation     0    0    0    0
         unemployed         0    0    0    0
94803    artistic           2    2    2    1
         banking            2    2    1    0
         clerical           0    2    1    0
         computer           0    2    0    1
         construction       5    2    0    0
         education          1    4    4    0
         entertainment      2    2    0    0
         executive          2    0    0    0
         hospitality        0    2    0    0
         law                2    0    1    0
         medicine           2    5    3    0
         military           0    1    1    0
         political          1    1    0    0
         retired            0    1    0    0
         sales              2    5    0    0
         science            2    4    0    0
         student            4    0    3    1
         transportation     0    1    1    0
         unemployed         0    0    0    0
94804    artistic           4   10    7    2
         banking            5    0    3    0
         clerical           0    2    3    1
         computer           7    6    5    2
         construction       7    7    6    0
         education         11    8    9    1
         entertainment      4    1    3    1
         executive          3    4    3    1
         hospitality        2    7    3    0
         law                2    5    0    1
         medicine           9    7    6    1
         military           2    2    0    0
         political          3    0    1    0
         retired            0    1    2    1
         sales             10    6    0    2
         science           10    5    3    1
         student           13   15   13    5
         transportation     1    1    1    0
         unemployed         1    1    3    0
94806    artistic           4    2    0    2
         banking            1    2    3    0
         clerical           1    1    0    0
         computer           4    2    2    0
         construction       4    4    3    1
         education          8    1    4    0
         entertainment      1    0    0    0
         executive          1    3    0    0
         hospitality        0    2    3    0
         law                1    1    2    0
         medicine           4    4    2    1
         military           2    2    1    0
         political          1    3    0    1
         retired            0    0    0    0
         sales              6    6    3    0
         science            3    4    2    1
         student           10    5    6    2
         transportation     3    2    2    0
         unemployed         0    1    3    1
94901    artistic          22    9   13    7
         banking           20   10    6    1
         clerical           2    0    5    1
         computer          21   12    4    6
         construction      18    2    1    0
         education         18   17   14    3
         entertainment     11    7    3    0
         executive         13    4    3    5
         hospitality        7    4    2    0
         law                5    4    4    0
         medicine          28   18   12    3
         military           0    0    0    0
         political          3    3    0    0
         retired            4    2    3    1
         sales             27   13    9    3
         science           15    1    4    0
         student           10   18    5   10
         transportation     0    0    2    0
         unemployed         0    1    2    1
94904    artistic           4    1    0    1
         banking            7    3    1    0
         clerical           0    1    0    0
         computer           1    2    1    0
         construction       1    0    0    0
         education          1    2    1    1
         entertainment      0    0    1    0
         executive          5    5    0    0
         hospitality        1    0    0    0
         law                0    1    0    1
         medicine           5    3    3    1
         military           0    0    0    0
         political          1    0    0    0
         retired            0    0    0    0
         sales              5    2    1    0
         science            5    1    2    0
         student            0    2    0    0
         transportation     0    0    0    0
         unemployed         0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Can you please provide data in a usable format? Best would be using a public database and adapt whatever process we suggest to your data; second would be building sample data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or similar); third would be posting the output from `dput(x)` where `x` here is a representative but not too big sample of your real data. Thanks.

Comment: Added raw data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R1NeFTuvvhqnxG-SgABevJjPflyaG_P1btmwyD2hB-c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should ask only one question for each post. I see 3 questions here.